# IupText MASK attribute for hex string input

Tags: iup

What should be the mask for iupText attribute MASK for entering a hexadecimal string of a certain length, for example, the 16-character sequence like 5A18F077D90ABB39?
All I could think of was 16 times [0-9a-fA-F].

Answer (score 0):

The mask "[0-9a-fA-F]+" will do the job for repeating the pattern. Setting also NC=16 attribute restricts the number of characters.